# Unwrapped shapes overlap in editor

Tags: mesh, uv, texture-painting, uv-image-editor

I'm trying to paint textures on different objects by UV mapping and painting - maybe I'm doing this wrong or in the wrong order, but whenever I select new shapes to work on and unwrap them, they open on the same image in the Image Editor, on top of each other - although I selected "New Image".

[image]

On the enclosed screenshot, you can see that the meshes are overlapping, which creates a confusing image.

I am trying to unwrap a new shape, which doesn't even shop up over the previous ones anymore...

**To reproduce this problem:**

- create new file; in new file create monkey head and ico sphere in Object mode;
- select monkey head in Object then in Edit mode, unwrap Monkey head and see it unwrapped in the UV/Image Editor
- create new Image in UV editor, click OK
- paint something on the unwrapped monkey head, save as image
- select ico sphere in object then in edit mode, unwrap it: where does the unwrapped image appear? Even if you create a "new image" in the UV editor, the ico sphere doesn't seem to show up anywhere.

**Another way to reproduce this:**

- create new file
- go in Edit Mode, add Torus and Monkey Head
- open UV Editor, create new image in UV Editor, in the Edit view, unwrap while all are selected
- notice how all shapes overlap in the unwrapped view
- create an ico sphere, unwrap it: where's the unwrapped version?

Comment: Does *Pack Islands* (Ctrl P) help?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? In which window would this shortcut be effective, and what am I supposed to see happen when I press it? (in 3D view it asks "make vertex parent?" and on the image editor, CTRL+P does nothing)

Comment: In the UV editor, but while in *View* mode. (Change *Paint* to *View* in the header, at the bottom of your screenshot). It should re-arrange separated parts of the UV map to cover as much area as possible without overlapping. You can tweak the margin and other settings in the *Redo* panel (F6) after running the operator.

Comment: Right, when I go to "View" mode in the UV Editor, I see a clean black image. But the old meshes are still there (visible in "paint" view). If I create a new image, the meshes from old objects are always visible in paint mode.

Comment: Are you in *edit mode* in the 3D view?

Comment: It should look like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/10Ly6.png).